# Docker image of Windows XP software

Tags: docker, windows-xp

Hi I hope I can find an answer if this is possible to do with Docker.

There are softwares I have that no longer run on moder Windows OS. For example, Macromedia Flash 5 that I used to run on Windows XP x86.

Is that possible to create an image for Micromedia Flash 5 to run on Windows 10 using Docker?

If the answer is yes, what would be directions for me to accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I would guess - they didn't consider this question on-topic for ServerFault as they see this as being a end user question. And it probably is really more suited for another channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with running Dockerized Windows applications. But the concept of Docker is that it shares the Kernel of the host OS. So most likely, your Windows XP / 7 applications that don't work on Windows 10 won't work in Docker either. Besides, from what I can tell, it's not particularly for running graphical interface programs but more for things like IIS or other server services that are headless.

This kind of scenario is best handled, in my opinion, with virtual machines. You can have a Windows XP virtual machine kicking around to run those older applications.

Comment: I appreciated the answer. The thing I scratch my head about Dockerization is, if I can run xp on vm, which I already do anyway, on hyper-v, why woudn't I be able to dockerize that since the vm itself is runs  on the host OS that, in this case, already doesn't share the same kernel.

Comment: Containers and Virtual Machines, while similar in very high level concepts, are quite different in technology and "capabilities". Virtual Machine is an entire machine emulated in software. Container is only isolation, not virtualization.

Comment: "The container’s system requires an underlying operating system that provides the basic services to all of the containerized applications using virtual-memory support for isolation. A hypervisor, on the other hand, runs VMs that have their own operating system using hardware VM support." https://www.electronicdesign.com/dev-tools/what-s-difference-between-containers-and-virtual-machines

Comment: https://dyn.com/blog/kubernetes-the-difference-between-containers-and-virtual-machines/